# Julia - describe() function display incomplete summary statistics

Tags: statistics, julia, summary

I'm trying basic data analysis with Julia

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/10/comprehensive-tutorial-learn-data-science-julia-from-scratch/) with the train datasets that can be found [here](https://github.com/umsh1ume/Loan-Prediction) (the one named `train_u6lujuX_CVtuZ9i.csv`) with the following code:

```
using DataFrames, RDatasets, CSV, StatsBase
train = CSV.read("/Path/to/train_u6lujuX_CVtuZ9i.csv");
describe(train[:LoanAmount])
```

and get this output:

```
Summary Stats:
Length:         614
Type:           Union{Missing, Int64}
Number Unique:  204
```

instead of the output of the tutorial:

```
Summary Stats:
Mean:           146.412162
Minimum:        9.000000
1st Quartile:   100.000000
Median:         128.000000
3rd Quartile:   168.000000
Maximum:        700.000000
Length:         592
Type:           Int64
% Missing:      3.583062
```

Which also corresponds to the output of [StatsBase.jl](https://juliastats.github.io/StatsBase.jl/stable/scalarstats.html#StatsBase.summarystats) that  the `describe()` function should give

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how it is currently (in the current release) implemented in StatsBase.jl. In short `train.LoanAmount` does not have `eltype` that is subtype of `Real` and then StatsBase.jl uses a fallback method that only prints length, eltype and number of unique values. You can write `describe(collect(skipmissing(train.LoanAmount)))` to get summary statistics (except number of missings of course).

Actually, however, I would recommend you to use another approach. If you want to get a more verbose output on a single column use:

```
describe(train, :all, cols=:LoanAmount)
```

you will get an output that additionally is returned as a `DataFrame` so that you can not only see the statistics but also access them.

Option `:all` will print all statistics please refer to `describe` docstring in DataFrames.jl to see available options.

You can find some examples of using this function on a current release of DataFrames.jl [here](https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial/blob/master/02_basicinfo.ipynb).

Comment: Many Thanks @BogumiłKamiński For that very precise answer (as always).

Comment: Kudos to excellent answer, thank you for your support of the community.  I tried syntax above and failed, but it worked with `describe(train[[:LoanAmount]], :all)` which matches the docstring definitions.

Comment: the syntax has changed during the last 18 months. I have updated the answer to match what works now.